How do I stretch a QDockWidget's child to the full size of the dock widget?
In the following minimum example, I have a main window with a dock widget with a child widget. I would like the child widget to take up the entire docked widget even as the docked widget resizes, but I'm not sure how to do that. I would think this is the default behavior with the dock widget providing "dockable" behavior, but otherwise yielding its drawing surface to the child entirely. I have set the child widget's size policy to Expanding, but that doesn't seem to be effective.
I added a red border to the child widget to see its size. When the application first starts, it looks like the docked widget is smaller than its containing main window, but the child widget is properly taking up the entire docked widget's client area:

If I click and drag the dock widget onto the main window (that's where it already is, but it causes the dock widget to re-dock with the main window), it is clear that the child widget didn't resize:

This is a minimum example. In my actual application, I have a layout in the child widget with several components. I want all the components to be able to stretch and scale to take the entire client area of the parent dock widget.
#include <QApplication>

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QScopedPointer>
#include <iostream>
#include <QDockWidget>

struct MyWidget : public QWidget {
    MyWidget(QWidget * parent = nullptr);
    QSize sizeHint() const override;
    QSize minimumSizeHint() const override;
};

struct MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) override;
private:
    QScopedPointer<MainWindow> ui;
    QDockWidget * dock;
    MyWidget * wid;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    dock = new QDockWidget(this);
    dock->setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid blue");
    wid = new MyWidget(dock);
    wid->setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid red");
    wid->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * e)
{
    QMainWindow::paintEvent(e);
    std::cout << "Dock's  size " << dock->width() << ',' << dock->height() << '\n';
    std::cout << "child's size " << wid->width() << ',' << wid->height() << '\n';
    std::cout << "child's sizehint    " << wid->sizeHint().width() << ',' << wid->sizeHint().height() << '\n';
    std::cout << "child's minsizehint " << wid->minimumSizeHint().width() << ',' << wid->minimumSizeHint().height() << '\n';
}

MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget * parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
}

QSize MyWidget::minimumSizeHint() const
{
    return QSize(153,154);
}

QSize MyWidget::sizeHint() const
{
    return QSize(150,151);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow mainWindow;
    mainWindow.show();
    return app.exec();
}

How do I get the child widget to completely fill the dock widget even as the dock widget resizes?

You're just creating both the dock and its widget as children, while you're never using two fundamental and required aspects of dock widgets: 1. QDockWidget::setWidget(); 2. QMainWindow::addDockWidget().

If you would post your comment as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Sorry, but I am not able to write accurate C++ code, and I don't normally have the habit of posting answers that just link the documentation, especially when it's clear and well written as Qt ones normally are. Feel free to post the answer on your own.

You need to call dock->setWidget(wid);. Your dock widget will also work better if you addDockWidget(dock);.

I didn't think I needed to dock->setWidget(wid) because when I created the child widget, I specified the dock widget as the parent (wid = new MyWidget(dock);...what does that do if not dock->setWidget(wid);?). I was trusting to the QT magic to set the child widget for me through this mechanism.
